# Assert some method is called with Consumer type as param in test

Tags: java, mockito

I have a simple function which call some method. One of the parameter I have to send to be of type Consumer. I was hoping the simplest test will be to assert the params but I am having hard time assert Consumer type.
My code looks something like this

```
@Component
public class MyService {
  @Autowired
  private SomeLib someLib;
    
  public void doSomething() {
    String someConfigValue = "hello";
    Consumer<SomeType> dataProcessor = this::processData;
    someLib.enhanceMethod(someConfigValue, dataProcessor)
  }

  private void processData(SomeType data) {
    log.info(data);
  }
}
```

And test I am trying to write is as follow

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyServiceTest {
  @Mock
  SomeLib someLib;
  
  @InjectMocks
  MyService myService;
  
  @Test
  public void shouldCallEnhanceMethodWithRightParams() {
    myService.doSomething();

    verify(someLib).enhanceMethod("hello", ???);  
  }
}
```

Any suggestion on how I can achieve this? Is there other alternative test I can write? I want to do test without using `PowerMock`

Updated: Code to have only one dependency and use simple string param as first param.

Comment: It's unclear whether you're trying to test `MyService` or `SomeOtherService`, and that's partially because your `SomeLib` seems to be acting like a plain passive library but your injection makes it look like a service instead. Explain in more detail what it does; the best approach may be "don't mock or inject `SomeLib` and assert on `mock.doMagicOn`".

Comment: Method under test is `doSomething` and trying to assert that method untimely called `someLib.enhanceMethod` with right params. Updated: example for simplicity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this

```
@Test
public void shouldCallEnhanceMethodWithRightParams() {
    myService.doSomething();

    verify(someLib).enhanceMethod(any(SomeConfigValue.class), any(Consumer.class));
}
```

Comment: `any()` seems to work. I was hoping we have some way to not use `any` if we have String type as one of the param. For example I want to explicitly test  "hello" string. I have updated code to reflect this. Any suggestion on updated one without using `any()`

Comment: got it ! . you mean first paramter type is String on enhanceMethod. you can try wrapp with `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers#eq(T)`